# AWS Lambda Triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a use case, wherein there is a Kinesis Stream (managed in a different AWS account), can this stream be configured with events that could trigger a lambda in our account (cross-account)? I know that lambda in case of Kinesis events polls the Kinesis stream so will this work similarly to how S3 events (push-based) in account A, triggers a lambda in account B? And further should both the resources be in the same region for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an Event Bus in CloudWatch where you'll provide permission to another account for that particular event(Action).